# Automatic syncing database on local server to remote server

Tags: mysql, database, django

I have developed a django application using MySQL as database engine.

I want my application to performing any action with database on the local machine then in an interval of time (suppose every 5 minutes) the local database sync to the database on the server automatically.

How can I do this kind of thing, using MySQL script or django can do it for me using its tools?

Comment: What do you mean by "local database"? Django doesn't run locally, it runs on the server.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I mean the database on the local server. Sorry for unclear words.

Comment: One way or 2 way? for what purpose?

Comment: @Thomas Just one way in order to make it can continue to work in case of the connection has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The term “[MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html)” is what you want~
But in factor it'll sync data whenever your data on the local server is changed~

Comment: This will not work unless your local machine can be accessed from the internet, either by a static IP address or a dynamic dns!